# Delete data with Angular and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I want to delete data with PHP and Angular form MySQL.
this is my code :

**Angular**

```
    $scope.delete = function(){
    that = this;
    $http.get("delete.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.users.splice(that.$index, 1)
    })
}
```

**PHP**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($data->subject);
mysql_select_db("angular") or die(mysql_error());

$tbl="Customers";
$subject = $_GET ['index'];
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl WHERE subject = '$subject'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if($result){
    echo "Deleted Successfully";

}else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

**DB**

```
I have a table "Customers" with subject and body cell
```

JavaScript code worked correctly but after refreshing data still alive !!
where am I wrong ?

Comment: This code is just waiting to be exploited with SQL injection the way that you've implemented it. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: How are you passing the parameter `index`?

Comment: you need to pass ANYTHING with the GET request from the angular side. but that's just begining... please start with topics like what are GET and POST and why is passing variables taken from them inside queries totally wrong idea...

Comment: Without seeing any more of the surrounding code, I suspect that the query being executed is: `DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Subject = ''`. How does index get passed in?

Comment: You probably should also strongly consider using POST instead of GET.  It would be trivial for someone to type `http://yourdomain.com/delete.php?index=xyz` in your browser to delete data from your database. POST would help prevent against this and would give you even better security if your verified a valid session token so someone could just form valid POST's against your endpoint to delete records.

Comment: oh- sry guys , i'm new ,
would you plz help me out ?

Answer (score 3):

## as mentioned in comments, **your code is vulnerable** to sql injection attacks

---

you need to add `subject` to your request

**angular**

```
$scope.delete = function(){
var subject = // get subject somehow ...
that = this;
$http.get("delete.php?subject=" + subject)
   .success(function(data){
       $scope.users.splice(that.$index, 1)
    })
}
```

**php**

```
$tbl="Customers";
$subject = $_GET ['subject'];
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl WHERE subject = '$subject'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if($result){
    echo "Deleted Successfully";

}else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: thx @Jossef but nothing happend , and i also updated my question about my db

Comment: note that `var subject = // get subject somehow ...` is something you need to complete by yourself

Comment: i added var subject = $scope.sentCompose;
$scope.sentCompose; is from send function but nothing happend